# post запрос на сторонний сервер

Tags: php, javascript, json, api

Как я могу отправить post запрос на сторонний сервер и получить ответ?

Тело запроса нужно отправлять в формате form-data

Comment: Откуда отправить?

Comment: С формы при загрузки страницы

Answer (score 2):

**Используя PHP**

Можно послать POST запрос используя [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// Или можно передать сразу массив с параметрами:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          array('postvar1' => 'value1'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Также можно послать запрос через [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: multipart/form-data',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Источник: [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

**Используя JavaScript**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'get_data.php';
var params = 'orem=ipsum&name=binny';
http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
http.send(params);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: А cors пропустить такой is?

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia CORS такой JS на **СТОРОННИЙ** сервер не пропустит.

Comment: А как тогда решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Send JSONP Cross-domain Requests [click here](http://json.com/2013/12/16/send-jsonp-cross-domain-requests.html)